# Can't install a single plugin on Eclipse 3.5

Tags: plugins, installation, eclipse-3.5

I'm trying to install the Subversion team provider on Eclipse 3.5, and it fails with the following message:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile,phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
 Result of processing steps.
Unpack facility not configured
OK
OK
Result of processing steps.
Unpack facility not configured
OK
OK
```

Not just SVN, try installing any plugin, and it fails to install. Isn't this a serious bug? 
Has anyone else seen it or is there a workaround?
Changing to a brand new workspace doesn't help either.

**Update**: The problem was a bug in IBM Java 6- unpack200.exe wasn't working properly. It's fixed now.

Comment: I needed to change my network connection preferences Active Provider from Native to Direct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Java are you running with? Java 5+ may be required. See [this email](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.equinox/msg06196.html)

Comment: I'm using IBM Java 6. Later I tried with Sun Java 6 and it works. So time to raise a bug for IBM JDK.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Java SDK from Sun and then started with the -vm option.
It seems that Eclipse used my GNU version of Java without the -vm option.

./eclipse -vm /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22/jre/bin/

Answer (score 1):

Right click on "My computer" -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables.

In "Path" under "System Variables", give your "bin" folder(in java/jre) path as the first parameter before DevSuite and other parameters.

This will solve the problem.

Thanks..!!

Comment: The problem was a bug with IBM Java, it worked fine with Sun Java. At the time I needed to use IBM Java for my work.